# Swift WKWebView "Error acquiring assertion" after updating to Xcode 11

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I appreciate help to resolve the following problem.
This problem appeared after I updated to Xcode 11.

A WKWebView opens a web page that contains an embedded Vimeo video.
The page loads and displays the embedded player.
When I tap on the video to play it, I received the following errors in the console:

> [assertion] Error acquiring assertion:  {
>       userInfo = {
>           RBSAssertionAttribute = ;
>       } }
>
> [ProcessSuspension]  0x1056fde38 - ProcessAssertion() PID 1887 Unable
>   to acquire assertion for process with PID 1887 2019-09-22
>   11:15:04.570119-0700 testWeb[1887:362082] [ProcessSuspension]
>   0x1056fde38 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
>   2019-09-22 11:15:04.576732-0700 testWeb[1887:362143] [assertion] Error
>   acquiring assertion:  {
>       userInfo = {
>           RBSAssertionAttribute = ;
>       } }
>
> [ProcessSuspension]  0x1056fde88 - ProcessAssertion() PID 1887 Unable
>   to acquire assertion for process with PID 1890 2019-09-22
>   11:15:04.577137-0700 testWeb[1887:362082] [ProcessSuspension]
>   0x1056fde88 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
>   2019-09-22 11:15:05.261258-0700 testWeb[1887:362150] [plugin]
>   AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id  F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46

This is running on Xcode 11 and the problem appears on the simulator and on devices running iOS 13 and iOS 12.

Comment: FWIW, I reverted to the previous version of Xcode and all is good.

Comment: I have the same (and other issues) with a YT video playing from a `WKWebView`.

Answer (score 1):

WKWebview modal presentation style is changed from Xcode 11 with iOS 13. 
I think this happens only if you have implemented some action on cancel or done and this is not handled.
Please note viewWillAppear also not called in this case.
Try implementing **willMove(toParent:)** or **isModalInPresentation**

Comment: what is need to be coded in willMove(toParent:) condition?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you implement willMove.  It stops the screen crash, but doesn't stop WKWebKit from crashing out.

```
override func willMove(toParent: UIViewController? ) {
    print("Something")
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In my case, I changed viewWillAppear to viewDidLoad, and this solved my problem.